# Random image in ASP.NET everytime the login form is visited

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I have the following code in ASP.NET to call a random image each time the user goes to the login page. It works great in Internet Explorer but it doesn't in the other browsers. What I am missing?

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Login</title>
<link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carrois+Gothic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('input:submit, input:reset').each(function () {
                $(this).replaceWith('<button type="submit" name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '" class="' + $(this).attr('class') + '" id="' + $(this).attr('id') + '" >' + $(this).val() + '</button>');
            });
            $("input:button, a, button", ".page").button();
            $("a", ".demo").click(function () { return false; });

    var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg', 'image6.jpg', 'image7.jpg', 'image8.jpg'];
    $('body').css({ 'background': 'url(img/loginBackground/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ') no-repeat fixed 100% 100%;' });

        });

</script>
```

Using this code doesn't solve my issue. It doesn't allow me to see the background on Internet Explorer or other:

```
    $("body").css({ 'background-image': 'url(img/loginBackground/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
$("body").css({'background-repeat':'no repeat'});
$("body").css({'background-size':'100% 100%'});
```

Comment: How do I debug the jQuery? I placed a breakpoint but it didnt stopped.

Comment: the best way is put your codes inside of $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: tried running the cose using $(document).ready(function(){}) but still I wasn't able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Works:

```
var imageUrl = 'img/loginBackground/' + images[num];
$('body').css('background-image', 'url("img/' + images[num]+'")');
$("body").css({'background-repeat':'no-repeat'});
$("body").css({'background-size':'100% 100%'});
```

Comment: $('body').css({ 'background': 'url("img/loginBackground/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + '") no-repeat fixed 100% 100%;' });

Tried the code above but still doesn't work.

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox - just tested it. Are you still missing double quoted?

Updated some code...

Answer (score 0):

set body's styles in separate lines.
try this:

```
var images = ['them1.png', 'them2.png', 'them3.png', 'them4.png'];
$("body").css({ 'background-image': 'url(skins/' +   
  images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')'});
$("body").css({'backgroundRepeat':'no repeat'});
$("body").css({'backgroundSize':'100% 100%'});
```

Comment: It doesn't run on IE or Chrome. I updated my code sample to give more details.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, I'll recreate a project later today to see if it something conflicting.